# Floating EEPROM (28c64A) pins an option?

Tags: ground, eeprom, floating-pin

I am building an eeprom programmer for the 28C64A (dip package) with my old basic stamp ii "homework" board (lost my arduino in the move). I have the first four address and data pins, as well as W E and G connected from P0 to P10. I am working with what I already have, so buying shift registers and friends is not an option. My question is that I read over the eeproms datasheet and it said nothing about leaving unconnected pins floating, so is it okay to do that, or must they be grounded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the part about input current. Close to zero, right? It's a CMOS chip, so you must tie all the inputs to appropriate logic levels (high or low, depending on what you want).

Comment: Just in case the "C" in the middle of the part number didn't give it away...